# Gradually create childs for displaying large data in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, large-data-volumes

I have a large ArrayCollection that need to be displayed in series of Datagrid.
After testing, the loading time is around 30secs-1minute.

My question here, is there a way to gradually add each datagrid and display it instead of waiting until all datagrids to fully created?

Existing :

- AddChild 1
- AddChild 2
- AddChild 3
- repeat until AddChild-x
- CreationComplete

My intended process :

- AddChild 1
- CreationComplete
- AddChild 2
- CreationComplete
- repeat until AddChild-x

My current implementation :

```
    <mx:VBox> 
        <mx:Repeater id="inputCategoryListMultiple">
            <renders:CustomPeriodGrid  data="{inputCategoryListMultiple.currentItem}"/>
        </mx:Repeater>
   </mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Data Paging may help you.

Have a look on the following:
http://www.jamesward.com/2010/10/11/data-paging-in-flex-4/